# How to install ember activemodel-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using `ember-rails` with `ember-source` and `ember-data-source`. But somehow the `activemodel-adapter` is not included in either of the gems. Or I'm missing something. I also searched bower, and can't find any. The code seems to be at: https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/master/packages/activemodel-adapter

But it also needs compile. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must explicitly load a recent version of Ember Data. For example, add a version to the ember-data-source gem in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'ember-data-source', '~> 1.0.0.beta.7'
```

Answer (score 0):

The active model adapter is included with Ember Data.  Assuming everything in your project is global you could use it for your entire application like so:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter;
```